# I'm getting this error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting this error in my query but does not see where the problem occurs. I'm still new to sql and need your help. The error appears at the last code "commandType.Text......" Here is my code.

```
public void DeletePaymentId(string paymentid)
 {
   _connectionString = ConnectionString = GetUrlForPaymentDb();
    var paymentId = SetupSqlConnection(
      $"DELETE p " +
      $"FROM[dbo].[Payment] p " +
      $"INNER JOIN[dbo].[Booking] b ON b.BookingNumber = p.BookingNumber " +
      $"WHERE p.PaymentId = '{paymentid}' ",
    
    CommandType.Text, cmd => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
}
```

Comment: CommandType.Text, cmd   Comma here looks a little bit strange. I also hope, you have provided paymentid

Comment: Yes, "paymentid" is passed as a parameter

Comment: @Sergey i've updated and written the whole function.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Query looks valid to me - what's the value of `paymentid` when you call this? -- BTW, having two variables whose names vary only in case is a code smell, IMHO.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `{paymentid}` uses interpolation. **Do NOT interpolate or concatenate queries, use proper SQL parameterization** `WHERE p.PaymentId = @paymentid` and pass in a `SqlParameter`, you should be able to declare the query as `const string`

Comment: @Charlieface: I know, I was referring to the fact that there's both `paymentid` and `paymentId`. FWIW, I agree that you should not do query parameter substitution this way.

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions and i don't seem to get it working. I'm not very much at home with parameterization, so i probably need to read more about it.

Comment: `FROM[dbo].[Payment] p` Stop cramming your code together. Separate the key word from the table name properly.

Comment: @SMor i already corrected that.